# Vue3 Wait till Child Component is Mounted

Tags: vuejs3

I want to wait for a child component to mount before rendering a tooltip. While waiting, I will have a placeholder to display to the user.

An example component would be:

```html
<template>
   <div v-if="!mounted">Loading...</div>
   <child-component></child-component>
</template>
<script>
export default defineComponent({
   setup() {
       const mounted = ref(false);       

       return { 
           mounted
       } 
   }
});
</script>
```

After doing research, it looks like Vue2 supports life-cycle hooks on the components, which would change the above code to:

```html
<template>
   <div v-if="!mounted">Loading...</div>
   <child-component @hook:mounted="mountedCheck"></child-component>
</template>
<script>
export default {
export default defineComponent({
   setup() {
       const mounted = ref(false);       
       const mountedCheck = () = {
           mounted.value = true;
       }       

       return { 
           mounted, mountedCheck
       } 
   }
});
}
```

However, I cant seem to get the `@hook:mounted` to work. Is there something similar in Vue3, or am I missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The child component needs to emit that hook

child:

```html
<script>
export default defineComponent({
  setup() {
    onMounted(() => {
      const { emit } = getCurrentInstance();
      emit('mounted');
    })
    return {};
  }
});
</script>
```

parent

```html
<template>
   <div v-if="!mounted">Loading...</div>
   <child-component @mounted="mountedCheck"></child-component>
</template>
```

Answer (score 6):

The syntax has changed in Vue3. Now you need to use `@vue:mounted` instead of `@hook:mounted`.
See [Vue 3 Migration Guide - VNode Lifecycle Events](https://v3-migration.vuejs.org/breaking-changes/vnode-lifecycle-events.html#vnode-lifecycle-events)  for details

Also, keep in mind that some event names like `destroyed` and `beforeDestroy` have been renamed to `unmounted` and `beforeUnmount` respectively in Vue3